# Can't connect to WiFi after suspend

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking, network-manager, iwlwifi

After resuming from suspend, the Network Manager detects my WiFi signal, but eventually gives up when trying to connect to it.

These fixes did not work:

```
$ sudo restart network-manager
$ sudo nmcli nm sleep false
$ sudo bash -c 'echo SUSPEND_MODULES=\"iwlwifi\" > /etc/pm/config.d/config'
```

Below are outputs of `dmesg | tail -30` in three situations.

When laptop is turned on, WiFi is connected and working.

```
$ dmesg | tail -30
[    6.479195] nouveau  [     CLK][0000:01:00.0] 0f: core 270-835 MHz memory 2000 MHz 
[    6.479339] nouveau  [     CLK][0000:01:00.0] --: core 405 MHz memory 324 MHz 
[    6.511984] vga_switcheroo: enabled
[    6.512140] [TTM] Zone  kernel: Available graphics memory: 4034782 kiB
[    6.512142] [TTM] Zone   dma32: Available graphics memory: 2097152 kiB
[    6.512143] [TTM] Initializing pool allocator
[    6.512146] [TTM] Initializing DMA pool allocator
[    6.512154] nouveau  [     DRM] VRAM: 2048 MiB
[    6.512155] nouveau  [     DRM] GART: 1048576 MiB
[    6.512159] nouveau  [     DRM] TMDS table version 2.0
[    6.512160] nouveau  [     DRM] DCB version 4.0
[    6.512162] nouveau  [     DRM] DCB outp 00: 02010300 00000000
[    6.512164] nouveau  [     DRM] DCB conn 00: 00000400
[    6.513365] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[    6.513366] [drm] No driver support for vblank timestamp query.
[    6.513376] nouveau  [     DRM] ACPI backlight interface available, not registering our own
[    6.524228] nouveau  [     DRM] MM: using COPY for buffer copies
[    6.534906] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: No connectors reported connected with modes
[    6.534907] [drm] Cannot find any crtc or sizes - going 1024x768
[    6.565439] nouveau  [     DRM] allocated 1024x768 fb: 0x80000, bo ffff880252922800
[    6.565572] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fb1: nouveaufb frame buffer device
[    6.565597] [drm] Initialized nouveau 1.1.2 20120801 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 1
[    6.867191] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[    6.871109] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[   14.819661] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20131115/nsarguments-95)
[   14.819773] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20131115/nsarguments-95)
[   34.230079] audit_printk_skb: 153 callbacks suppressed
[   34.230081] type=1400 audit(1420504569.736:62): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=2606 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   34.230086] type=1400 audit(1420504569.736:63): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=2606 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   34.230384] type=1400 audit(1420504569.736:64): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=2606 comm="apparmor_parser"
```

Right after resuming from suspend, when Network Manager is trying to connect.  WiFi icon is flashing.

```
$ dmesg | tail -30
[ 5835.278403] wlan0: authenticated
[ 5835.281414] wlan0: associate with 20:aa:4b:71:61:ef (try 1/3)
[ 5835.389401] wlan0: associate with 20:aa:4b:71:61:ef (try 2/3)
[ 5835.429510] wlan0: associate with 20:aa:4b:71:61:ef (try 3/3)
[ 5835.463202] wlan0: association with 20:aa:4b:71:61:ef timed out
[ 5835.981063] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20131115/nsarguments-95)
[ 5835.981273] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20131115/nsarguments-95)
[ 5836.451345] wlan0: authenticate with 20:aa:4b:71:61:ef
[ 5836.455839] wlan0: send auth to 20:aa:4b:71:61:ef (try 1/3)
[ 5836.458444] wlan0: authenticated
[ 5836.460831] wlan0: associate with 20:aa:4b:71:61:ef (try 1/3)
[ 5836.568785] wlan0: associate with 20:aa:4b:71:61:ef (try 2/3)
[ 5836.571480] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 20:aa:4b:71:61:ef (capab=0x411 status=1 aid=5)
[ 5836.571487] wlan0: 20:aa:4b:71:61:ef denied association (code=1)
[ 5837.236668] wlan0: deauthenticating from 20:aa:4b:71:61:ef by local choice (reason=3)
[ 5838.717178] wlan0: authenticate with 20:aa:4b:71:61:ef
[ 5838.721191] wlan0: send auth to 20:aa:4b:71:61:ef (try 1/3)
[ 5838.723777] wlan0: authenticated
[ 5838.727683] wlan0: associate with 20:aa:4b:71:61:ef (try 1/3)
[ 5838.751269] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 20:aa:4b:71:61:ef (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=5)
[ 5838.755381] wlan0: associated
[ 5841.893920] wlan0: deauthenticated from 20:aa:4b:71:61:ef (Reason: 2)
[ 5841.901569] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[ 5841.906314] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[ 5841.906319] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[ 5841.906323] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 5841.906326] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 5841.906328] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 5841.906330] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 5841.906333] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
```

A minute or so after the above state, it stops trying to connect.  WiFi icon is empty.  A notification pops up saying "Disconnected - you are now offline".

```
$ dmesg | tail -30
[ 5932.449208] wlan0: authenticate with 20:aa:4b:71:61:ef
[ 5932.452768] wlan0: send auth to 20:aa:4b:71:61:ef (try 1/3)
[ 5932.455454] wlan0: authenticated
[ 5932.456978] wlan0: associate with 20:aa:4b:71:61:ef (try 1/3)
[ 5932.480497] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 20:aa:4b:71:61:ef (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=5)
[ 5932.484791] wlan0: associated
[ 5935.611797] wlan0: deauthenticated from 20:aa:4b:71:61:ef (Reason: 2)
[ 5935.625479] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[ 5935.630150] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[ 5935.630156] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[ 5935.630159] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 5935.630162] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 5935.630164] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 5935.630167] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 5935.630169] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 5947.144676] wlan0: authenticate with 20:aa:4b:71:61:ef
[ 5947.148096] wlan0: send auth to 20:aa:4b:71:61:ef (try 1/3)
[ 5947.150573] wlan0: authenticated
[ 5947.153610] wlan0: associate with 20:aa:4b:71:61:ef (try 1/3)
[ 5947.177143] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 20:aa:4b:71:61:ef (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=5)
[ 5947.181446] wlan0: associated
[ 5950.313613] wlan0: deauthenticated from 20:aa:4b:71:61:ef (Reason: 2)
[ 5950.323551] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[ 5950.328210] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[ 5950.328215] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[ 5950.328219] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 5950.328221] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 5950.328224] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 5950.328226] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 5950.328228] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
```

Comment: After going through suspend and failing to connect, what does this command in terminal tell `dmesg | tail -30`

Comment: @Jeremy31 I added output of `dmesg | tail -30` in different three situations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2218043):

Type these lines of code in the terminal one at a time:

```
sudo touch /etc/pm/sleep.d/wakenet.sh
sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/wakenet.sh
sudo gedit /etc/pm/sleep.d/wakenet.sh
```

Then in the Gedit window that opens up, copy paste this text and press save.

```
#!/bin/bash
case "$1" in
thaw|resume)
sudo nmcli nm sleep false
sudo pkill -f wpa_supplicant
;;
*)
;;
esac
exit $?
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work.

Comment: Even after rebooting?

Comment: I tried this modification and it solved the issue: add `sudo` before `nmcli nm sleep false` and `pkill -f wpa_supplicant`.

Comment: Cool. Let me edit the answer and include that.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below command and restart the network manager,

```
sudo service dbus restart

sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: `sudo service dbus restart` turned my screen black and my cursor into a black "X" with a white outline

Comment: Running the second command (`sudo service network-manager restart`) fixed it for me

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know about programming but i had this issue and to make it work I just needed to unchecked the automatically connect to this network when available box , and check the allow all users to connect to this network box
all this is in the network connections--> edit connections --> general

Answer (score 0):

It might be an issue with your wifi firmware. Here's an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/624746/194207) to a similiar question that might help you:

> Download the brcmfmac43602 firmware from the Linux firmware git repo
>
> Copy it to /lib/firmware/brcm
>
> Reboot and enjoy your WiFi.

I tried it on a MacBook Pro 12,1 and it helped resolve this issue (as well as an issue with WPA2 networks)